# search by character ordered by value Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, social-networking, cql

search by character ordered by value Cassandra:

I am currently in the process of mastering cassandra with a first project. This one is a social network. I am working on the search bar to find users in the network. I'm looking for the best db organization as well as the best cql command to retrieve a list of 5 users starting from a score (float by descending order) as well as the first character of the pseudo of this one that the user entered.
Here is my idea to organize the cassandra table

```
CREATE TABLE user_classement (id int, user_name set<text>, score float,PRIMARY KEY(id, score))WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (score DESC) ;
create index on user_classement  (user_name);
```

Here is my idea to organize the cassandra table

```
INSERT INTO user_classement(id, user_name, score) VALUES (678, {'j', 'je', 'jes', 'jesv', 'jesve'}, 89,6);
```

The problem is that this organisation is not at all optimised and does not work with a ***contains*** in the cql command

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to achieve this with Cassandra. You can check out this post.

[Wildcard search in cassandra database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681522/wildcard-search-in-cassandra-database)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).